# phpmailer no funciona GMAIL

Tags: php, gmail, smtp, mail

Tengo un problema con `phpmailer`, tengo un formulario que debe de guardar en la base de datos y mandar un correo, hace lo primero pero no envía el correo:

Estoy usando `phpmailer` este es el código:

```
        require 'class.phpmailer.php';
        require 'class.smtp.php';
        $email_user = "ojedamaroje@gmail.com"; //Mi correo
        $email_password = ""; //Pass de mi correo
        $the_subject = "Mensaje de contacto";
        $address_to = "ojedamaroje@gmail.com";
        $from_name = "Contacto norte";
        $phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
        // ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail ---------------------
        $phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
        $phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
        $phpmailer->Port = 587;
        $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
        $phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
        $phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
        $phpmailer->Body ="
             Nombre: {$nombre} <br>
            Email: {$email} <br>
            Telefono: {$telefono} <br>
            LLmada de regreso ?: {$llamada}<br>
            Website: {$web}<br>
            Prioridad: {$prioridad}<br>
            Tipo servicio: {$tipo}<br>
            Mensaje: <p> {$mensajee} </p>
        ";
        $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
        $phpmailer->Send();
```

No sé sí me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Te sale algo en los logs? el servidor SMTP seguro está respondiendo con algún código que puede ayudar a resolver el problema. Por otra parte, qué versión de PHPMailer estás usando?

Comment: ¿Has habilitado en el Gmail, la opción de "less secure applications"?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 2):

Me late que te hace falta configurar cosas del lado de Gmail:

1. Dirígete hacia esta url: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. Realiza la activación de dicha opción.

Esto NO funciona si la cuenta que vas a utilizar para enviar correos tiene la autenticación de 2 pasos (mediante SMS).

Answer (score 1):

Yo recomiendo validar varias cosas:

- Confirmar usando como referencia este bloque de código:

  ```
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // habilita SMTP
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errores y mensajes, 2 = sólo mensajes
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // auth habilitada
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // transferencia segura REQUERIDA para Gmail
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password = "password";
  $mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
  $mail->Subject = "Test";
  $mail->Body = "hello";
  $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
      echo "Message has been sent";
   }
  ```

  - Revisa que en tu cuenta de GMail esté habilitada la opción para que se conecten "less secure apps". Sin esta validación, no es posible para aplicaciones que no usen OAuth2.0, el usar tu cuenta GMail. (el log de tu PHP sería de ayuda porque el servidor SMTP de GMail respondería que ingreses a través de un navegador...)
  - Procura que, si usas autenticación tls, uses el puerto 587; si usas ssl, usa el puerto 465.
  - Revisa que esté la extensión openssl en tu instalación de PHP para que la autenticación ssl sea posible.
  - Siempre revisa los logs del servidor donde corre PHP para revisar cómo fue interpretado y ejecutado tu código.

Fuente: [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048485/236345)